# Boxplot with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataframe called `cells`, with cells in rows and samples in columns, here is a dput sample:

```
structure(c(8.10937548981953e-20, 0.095381661829093, 0.054868371418562, 
0.0523687378840825, 0.0100173293159538, 0.0332395245437795, 3.37811149975583e-20, 
0.048191378909587, 0.13314908462763, 0, 0.00612878313809124, 
0, 0.00209460699328093, 0.205599458004829, 0.318048653115709, 
4.21796249339787e-05, 0.00844407692255898, 0, 0.00613007026042523, 
0.0300024082993193, 0.0405191646567986, 0.00654087887823056, 
0.0111094954094255, 1.30617589099212e-19, 0.0398730537850546, 
0.0390946117756341, 0.239413780024853, 2.07521807718399e-19, 
0.00116980239850497, 0, 0, 0.00971921247886335, 0.0588607291731613, 
3.8563512241696e-21, 0.00247621905821516, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 6L
), .Dimnames = list(c("Adipocytes", "B-cells", "Basophils", "CD4+ memory T-cells", 
"CD4+ naive T-cells", "CD4+ T-cells"), c("Pt1", "Pt10", "Pt103", 
"Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17")))
```

number of rows in `cells` is 38 and number of columns is 49.
My target cell type that I want to build a boxplot for is: `CD4+ memory T-cells`

In addition, have another data frame called `Metadata`, which contains the response column, if a sample responded to a certain therapy or not - `Metadata$Benefit`. So for each sample in `cells` I can know whether they responded or not.

**Goal**: make a boxplot with Response/No Response in the x axis and values on the y axis, and I need the boxplot with the indiviudal data points on it.

**My code**:

```
cells %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = as.factor(Metadata$Benefit), y = as.numeric(cells['CD4+ memory T-cells',]), fill= c('red','lightblue'))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
  geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_text(size=11)
  ) +
  ggtitle("A boxplot with jitter") +
  xlab("")
```

**Error**: `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (38): x, y and fill`

I don't get what's the problem because both `length(as.factor(Metadata$Benefit))` and `length(as.numeric(cells['CD4+ memory T-cells',]))` is 49, it's the same so what's the problem?

Comment: Your example data is not a data frame. And your ggplot code looks wrong - you cannot combine x and y variables from different data frames in that way.

Comment: The error says the data has 38 usable values (perhaps some are NA?), so if you are matching vectors that are 49 or 2 long, they won't match. I suggest you merge the data upstream of ggplot2 so that it just receives one data frame.

Comment: Can you share the `Metadata` in your question. But agreed with @JonSpring that you should merge those before passing to ggplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your attempt here as mentioned in the comments. You can't take `x` and `y` aesthetics from different `data` sources so you should merge them first. This also means rotating (for which I used `t()` while it was still a matrix) the original data prior to merging so each sample is a row. To demonstrate this I made up some response metadata.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(c(8.10937548981953e-20, 0.095381661829093, 0.054868371418562, 0.0523687378840825, 0.0100173293159538, 0.0332395245437795, 3.37811149975583e-20, 0.048191378909587, 0.13314908462763, 0, 0.00612878313809124, 0, 0.00209460699328093, 0.205599458004829, 0.318048653115709, 4.21796249339787e-05, 0.00844407692255898, 0, 0.00613007026042523, 0.0300024082993193, 0.0405191646567986, 0.00654087887823056, 0.0111094954094255, 1.30617589099212e-19, 0.0398730537850546, 0.0390946117756341, 0.239413780024853, 2.07521807718399e-19, 0.00116980239850497, 0, 0, 0.00971921247886335, 0.0588607291731613, 3.8563512241696e-21, 0.00247621905821516, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("Adipocytes", "B-cells", "Basophils", "CD4+ memory T-cells", "CD4+ naive T-cells", "CD4+ T-cells"), c("Pt1", "Pt10", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17")))

metadata <- data.frame(sample = c("Pt1", "Pt10", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17"), response = c(T, T, T, F, F, F))

d %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("sample") %>% 
  right_join(metadata, .) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = response, y = `CD4+ memory T-cells`)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = response)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','lightblue'))
#> Joining, by = "sample"
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>